# Network byte order endianness conversion

Tags: c, endianness

I have the following:

```
#define IPADDR "\xc0\x80\x10\x0a" /* 192.168.1.10 */
#define PORT "\x7a\x69" /* 31337 */
```

However I can't for the life of me figure out how the hex values would equal the ASCII values. How would I go about changing it to a different IP or port number?

Basically how do I get from the IP to the \xc0\x80\x10\x0a and vice versa?

In short, I am looking at http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-857.php and would like to know how they arrived ad that long string

Thanks

Comment: The long string is just the machine code from the disassembly listing above it. That one starts with `48 31 c0 ` and ends with `0f 05`. So does the string.

Comment: The first string cannot be decoded into the comment address, no matter what byte order or endianness you use.  At least one of them is wrong.   168 = 0xa8 and that's nowhere in your address, not even reversed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about getting there, it's just a different way of representing the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define IPADDR "\xc0\x80\x10\x0a" /* not 192.168.1.10  */
                                  /* but 192.128.16.10 */

#define PORT "\x7a\x69"           /* not 31337 */
                                  /* but 27002 */

#define c2ui(a) ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)a)

int main()
{
    printf("\n%u.%u.%u.%u\n", c2ui(IPADDR[0]),
                              c2ui(IPADDR[1]),
                              c2ui(IPADDR[2]),
                              c2ui(IPADDR[3]));

    printf("\n\\x%02x\\x%02x\\x%02x\\x%02x\n", c2ui(IPADDR[0]),
                                               c2ui(IPADDR[1]),
                                               c2ui(IPADDR[2]),
                                               c2ui(IPADDR[3]));
    union
    {
        uint8_t s_port[3];
        uint16_t v_port;
    } v;
    memcpy(v.s_port, (uint8_t *)&PORT[0], sizeof(PORT));
    printf("\nport: %u\n", v.v_port);
}
```

Apart from the fact that there are errors in the descriptions that I have pointed out in the example code. In the case of PORT instead there is a problem because the fact that that number is correct depends on the type of system on which that program will run. On my system, for example, to get the value as in the description I would have had to invert the two characters. For this reason it is not a good idea to use that type of format for values. It would have been better if it had written:

```
#define PORT 31337                /* 31337 */
```

Comment: "\x7a\x69" is port 31337.  port 27002 would be "\x69\x7a"

Comment: @Chris Dodd: ops... I had inverted it from the original to do a test. Now I correct it

Answer (score 0):

There are standard functions nthos/htons/ntohl/htonl to convert 16- and 32-bit values (basically, port numbers and ipv4 addresses) between network and host byte order.  So for example:

```
sockaddr_in  addr;

addr.sin_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);  // loopback address converted to network order
addr.sin_port = htons(31337);  // convert port to network order
```